# jQuery reloading xml doc requires browser close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have some code that is working to pull an xml value using jQuery `$.ajax` however once the application is running in the browser any changes to the xml .doc and a subsequent browser refresh does not display the new saved xml value `xmlImagePath`.

What can be done to force the new xml value on browser refresh?

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Images/referal_Image_Config.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            //read xml file
            $(xml).find('image').each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('active') == 'true') {
                    var xmlImagePath = $(this).find('pathName').text();
```

Comment: GET requests cache. That is how the web works.

Comment: Closing as a dupe. Ignore the IE part of the other answer as it holds for the other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `cache` property of `$.ajax` to `false`:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Images/referal_Image_Config.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    cache: false,
    success: function (xml) {
        // your code...
    }
 });
```